# JPG image not displaying in Chrome, Firefox & Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an image being displayed in my website which runs fine on Safari however when I run this in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera it does not display for me.

The code I have is:

```
<img class = "header" src="./images/websitelogo.jpg" alt=" Header Image"/>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before and if so how did you resolve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at console. It would log 404 with red text

Comment: Is the markup you included above the exact replica of your webpage ? coz  the '.' in front of the '/' is not necessary. If you want an image from the root directory folder you can use, "../images/websitelogo.jpg"

Comment: @ItAssistors But then, the OP has mentioned in his post that the code works in Safari..

Comment: Hi I made the below change and still have the same issue. I checked the (inspect element) console and it says could not load image when I hover over the image link. Appreciate it if you have any other advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your path is wrong. If you are working in index file ,and u have another folder with pictures ,there's no reeason for you to have "." and /.

```
<img class = "header" src="images/websitelogo.jpg" alt=" Header Image"/>
```

It should look like this.

Comment: Hi I made the above change and still have the same issue. I checked the (inspect element) console and it says could not load image when I hover over the image link. Appreciate it if you have any other advice. Thanks

Comment: try to remove the extra spaces between class   =    "header".

Comment: spaces removed still same issue. I find it strange that it works in Safari but not other browsers. I have a mac computer though unless that may affect it

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the console log. I think the problem is in the img src you are searching image in ./images/websitelogo.jpg, but the images folder is in the same hierarchy as your html page, So replace your src to images/websitelogo.jpg

```
<img class = "header" src="images/websitelogo.jpg" alt=" Header Image"/>
```

Comment: Hi I made the above change and still have the same issue. I checked the (inspect element) console and it says could not load image when I hover over the image link. Appreciate it if you have any other advice. Thanks

Comment: Check the network whether the file has downloaded from the reference.